# Python programming output is not as expected

Tags: python, api, rest

I tried to automate the login for github api from "https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/"
I am getting error code 401 in response. Kindly guide me if my code is not good.
Please find the code below.
**NOTE:**
Configuration.py, properties.ini, credentials.py are under Utilities package.

**Login.py**

```
import requests
import configparser
from Utilities.Credentials import *
from Utilities.configuration import *

url_login = get_Config() ['API'] ['endpoint']

github_Res = requests.get(url_login, auth= (getUsername() , getPassword()), )

print(url_login)

Status_Code = github_Res.status_code

print(Status_Code)

if Status_Code == 200:
    print("User logged in Successfully.")
else:
    print("User log in failed!!")
```

**Configuration.py**

```
import configparser


def get_Config():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('Utilities/properties.ini')
    return config
```

**credentials.py**

```
def getUsername():
    return "***********@****.com"


def getPassword():
    return "********"
```

**properties.ini**

```
[API]
endpoint = https://api.github.com/user
```

Comment: `401` is unauthorised error code. check if you credentials are correct. Also check if github api you are using supports username/password login

Comment: Couple points here.
1. Authentication is usually done using a POST request, not a GET request. I'm not familiar with the specifics for the GitHub API but that struck me as odd.
2. When authenticating, data is usually encoded into a form, not inserted into the authentication header.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have two problems here:

1. You're trying to make a GET request when authentication usually requires a POST request.
2. You're sending the login credentials in the authentication header, not as form data.

Try doing it like this:

```
data = {"username": getUsername(), "password": getPassword()}
github_Res = requests.post(url_login, data = data)
```

Note that you'll probably still have issues because you haven't included the grant type or scope in your request.

**UPDATE**

I looked up GitHub's [API documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/basics-of-authentication) and it appears that it doesn't support username-password authentication anymore. You should probably rethink your solution to use a username and personal access token.

Comment: Hey @Woody1193 .. Thanks for your reply. I tried the modification sent by you but as you have said it is not working. I am getting the same 401 error.

Comment: @AnsumanPrasadPati I'm not sure what the use case for your code is but if GitHub authentication is necessary then I would suggest using access code and secret authentication. GitHub recommends that